# SimpleCursorAdapter ListView created by messagehandler

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I've read through all posts I can find about simplecursoradapter and listview but I still can't seem to find the answer to my problem.
I have an Activity which contains a number of radio buttons, a button and a listview. The Activity first makes an http request to a web server to retrieve some data. The data from the server is written to the sqlite db on the device. Once data has been written to the db, the Activity regains control and creates a Cursor from the db, a SimpleCursorAdapter and sets the adapter as the listview adapter. All data is written ok to the db, I have looped through the elements in the cursor and it contains all expected elements, still no elements is displayed in my listview.

Activity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private RadioButton rb1, rb2;
private Button addBut;
private ListView lv;
private LinearLayout statusLayout;
private ScrollView scroll;
private String username;
private DBHelper db;
private Cursor cursor;
private static final String userfk = "1";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb1.setChecked(true);
    rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    addBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    statusLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.statusLayout);
    scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.configscroll);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.profilesll);
    //get data from server, made in asynchtask   
    getData();
}
```

MessageHandler called from AsynchTask code:

```
private class MyHandler extends Handler {
public MyHandler() {
}
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final Bundle b = msg.getData();
        if (b.getString("result").equalsIgnoreCase(MyResult.ERROR) || b.getString("result").equalsIgnoreCase(MyResult.FAIL)) {
                 //Handle error
        } else {
            handleList();
            statusLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

private void handleList() {
    if (db == null) {
        db = new DBHelper(this);
    }
    if (cursor == null) {
        try {
            cursor = db.getListCursor(userfk);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            err = e.getMessage();
        }
        if (cursor == null) {
       Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, err != null ? err : getResources().getString(R.string.myerror), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[] {DBHelper.COLUMN_ID}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("test", e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("test", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DBHelper class

```
public Cursor getListCursor(String userfk) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("select name as _id from mytable where  userfk=?");
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add(userfk);
    try {
        return this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(builder.toString(), values.toArray(new String[values.size()]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to declare adapter outside Handler. Do it in Activity and assign it value in Handler

Comment: can you show the part of code where MyHandler is initialized? is it done in ui thread?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I moved the declaration of the cursor and simplecursoradapter and after a lot of testing I finally found out... that the problem was in the layout file.